# Dynamic HTML Tag generated from JavaScript, two-word class not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create dynamic html from an api response. Whenever I get a two-word class name, I cannot get it to save both words as the string is ending when it see's the space. See below:

```
for(var i = 0; i<articles.posts.length; i++){
    var cls = 'fa '+articles.posts[i].category;     
    var el = "<article><i class="+cls+"></i><h2> From the Archive </h2><h1> " + articles.posts[i].title + "</h1><h3> " + articles.posts[i].date + " </h3><p> " + articles.posts[i].blurb + "</p></article>"

    $("#article-list").last().append(el);
}
```

For Instance if 'cls' is fa fa-space-shuttle, the class gets set as 'fa' not both 'fa fa-space-shuttle'. Any idea how to get around this using javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Whenever I get a two-word class name

There are no two-word class names. What you have there is two classes.

> ```
> var el = "<article><i class="+cls+"></i><h2> From the Archive </h2><h1> " + articles.posts[i].title + "</h1><h3> " + articles.posts[i].date + " </h3><p> " + articles.posts[i].blurb + "</p></article>"
> ```

Look closely at the quotes in that line of code. There aren't any around the `class` attribute. So, according to the HTML specification, the value ends at the first space. Add quotes around it:

```
var el = "<article><i class='"+cls+"'></i><h2> From the Archive </h2><h1> " + articles.posts[i].title + "</h1><h3> " + articles.posts[i].date + " </h3><p> " + articles.posts[i].blurb + "</p></article>"
// -------------------------^-------^
```

Example:

```js
var cls = "fa fa-link";
var el = "<article><i class='"+cls+"'></i><h2> From the Archive </h2></article>"
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", el);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: The problem is that if you put quotes around 'cls', it will be the class 'cls'. I don't want that. I need to be able to generate the class dynamically from the api response.

Comment: @trebek1: No, it won't. The above puts `'` in the output string, around whatever the **value** of `cls` is.